# Sort by name ASC with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to sort by name ascending, values that are coming from DB by JPA. I need to sort `Categories`, `Subcategories`(which are child of category object), and `GlobalTags`. All three are inheriting from Tag class.

This is my Repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface TagDao extends JpaRepository<Tag, Long> {

    List<Tag> findTagsByNameAndTagType(String tagName, String tagType);
}
```

This is `ServiceImpl` of `findAllTags()`.

```
        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        @Override
        public ResponseGetTagsDto findAllTags() {
            Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>(tagDao.findAll());
            Set<Tag> globalTags = tags.stream().filter(tag -> GLOBAL == TagType.valueOf(tag.getTagType().toUpperCase())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            Set<Tag> categoryTags = tags.stream().filter(tag -> CATEGORY == TagType.valueOf(tag.getTagType().toUpperCase())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            Set<SubcategoryTag> subcategoryTags = tags.stream().filter(tag -> SUBCATEGORY == TagType.valueOf(tag.getTagType().toUpperCase())).map(SubcategoryTag.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
            log.info("found tags: {}", tags);
            return ResponseGetTagsDto.builder()
                    .globalTags(globalTags.stream()
                            .map(globalTag ->
                                    GlobalTagDto.builder()
                                            .id(globalTag.getId())
                                            .name(globalTag.getName())
                                            .tagType(globalTag.getTagType())
                                            .build()).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                    .categoryTags(categoryTags.stream()
                            .map(ct -> CategoryTagDto.builder()
                                    .id(ct.getId())
                                    .name(ct.getName())
                                    .tagType(ct.getTagType())
                                    .subcategoryTags(subcategoryTags.stream()
                                            .filter(subcategoryTag -> subcategoryTag.getCategoryTag().getId().equals(ct.getId()))
                                            .map(subcategoryTag -> SubcategoryTagDto.builder()
                                                    .id(subcategoryTag.getId())
                                                    .name(subcategoryTag.getName())
                                                    .tagType(subcategoryTag.getTagType())
                                                    .parentTagId(ct.getId())
                                                    .build())
                                            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                                    )
                                    .build())
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                    )
                    .build();
        }
```

I tried to do something like this: [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-sorting], but I get unsorted data when accessing it in Postman.

Comment: Have you tried findTagsByNameAndTagTypeOrderByNameAsc(...

Comment: Yes, I tried but when changing tag.findTagsByNameAndTagTypeOrderByNameAsc() method with tagDao.findAll(), I need to pass 2 arguments, name and tagType, and I don't know what to pass. ((

Comment: You pass the values that you want to filter your data on, like tagDao.findTagsByNameAndTagTypeOrderByNameAsc("aName", "GLOBAL")
by the looks of it shouldnt you be filtering only on tagtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were I was using `Set` to store data after retrieving it from DB with JPA query. `Set` doesn't store data ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 3 different repositories, one for each tag.

```
@Repository
public interface GlobalTagRepository extends JpaRepository<GlobalTag, Long> { 
     Set<GlobalTag> findAllOrderByNameAsc();
}
```

And similar ones for the other ones.
Then instead of filtering it manually I would

```
Set<GlobalTag> globalTags = new HashSet<>(GlobalTagRepository.findAllOrderByNameAsc());
Set<Category> categoryTags = new HashSet<>(CategoryTagRepository.findAllOrderByNameAsc());
Set<SubCategory> subCategoryTags= new HashSet<>(SubCategoryTagRepository.findAllOrderByNameAsc());
```

And then put them into a map and return it.

Comment: findAllOrderByNameAsc() doesn't work, I tried something like this but result of Stream .collect is ignored---------> Set<GlobalTag> globalTags = new HashSet<>(globalTagDao.findGlobalTagsByTagTypeAndNameOrderByName("GLOBAL", "name"));
     globalTags.stream().filter(tag -> GLOBAL == TagType.valueOf(tag.getTagType().toUpperCase())).collect(Collectors.toSet());